# 'Given a choice' vs.'If I had to choose'

Tags: phrases, expressions, word-usage

Can the phrases *given a choice* and *if I had to choose* be used interchangeably?

I made a statement like "Given a choice, I would do this," my original intention being to select that over the other option. But it was misinterpreted as "I did not want to do the other option," and I was told that I should have used "If I had to choose between the two."

Some inputs would be highly appreciated

Comment: I don't understand the distinction *you're* making, but idiomatically we don't use these two expressions interchangeably. You say *given a choice* when in fact you ***don't have the option of making a choice***, and are [to some extent, reluctantly] accepting something that isn't your first preference. You say *if I had to choose* when strictly speaking you're ***not required to choose***, and you have little preference between the available options (but you say which you would opt for if you ***had*** to choose ***one only***, and thereby reluctantly "reject" the alternatives).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's a good answer - why not make it one?

Comment: @TrevorD: Because I don't understand what OP's getting at (i.e. - what did he *mean* to convey when he made his original statement). If he just doesn't understand the difference between *not being allowed to exercise choice when you have a definite preference*, and *being forced to make an embarrassing and/or borderline choice when you don't want to*, then I think it's probably General Reference for ELU (but I wouldn't object to it on [learners.se](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: @FumbleFingers It seems that OP hasn't (yet) made a re-appearance on this site since asking the question!

Comment: Good answer by @FumbleFingers.  I would add that there is some suggestion, for me at least, that (a) in "given a choice" I might *want* to choose (but as you suggest, I might not be able to) and (b) in "if I had to choose" I might not *want* to choose (even if I had to, as you suggest).

Answer (score 1):

"Given a choice" considers the situation where you have the freedom of choosing as a hypothetical. It therefore suggests that you would very strongly favour the option you then describe.

Consider what it implies in the negative; that the only reason you would ever go for the other possibility is that you had no choice (you either had to do both, or had the decision made for you by factors outside your control).

"If I had to choose" considers an almost opposite hypothetical situation; you are forced to choose between the two, and the option of doing both or doing neither is not allowed. It therefore suggests you would very much prefer to do both or very much prefer to do neither (just which may or may not be clear from context).